# How can I set the email sender's name in Jenkins using gmail smtp?

Tags: gmail, jenkins

I'm setting up a Jenkins server. I got it sending emails through my gmail apps account. The problem is when I receive an email from Jenkins the sender's name is empty (I just see the email address used to authenticate with gmail's smtp), which makes it difficult to set a filter or distinguish Jenkins emails from the rest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. SMTP servers of Gmail override this info.